# Intuition for finding a circumcenter using cross products?

Tags: metric-geometry

The popular way to determine the circumcenter of a triangle is to find the intersection of two perpendicular bisectors, but I noticed the [wikipedia page for circumscribed circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_from_cross-_and_dot-products) also describes a method involving cross products and dot products -- no intersections!  Is there an intuitive explanation for that particular formula?

Comment: The first step of understanding where it came from is to drop this "no intersections" concept, which is actively preventing you from seeing the source.